# How to merge piece by piece

Tags: git, github

I want to merge from feature_branch to master, but not all in one piece, as that could lead to hard-to-debug problems.

I merged some of the changes manually, pushed them to github, and did a "compare master with feature_branch" in github. I expected this to show fewer changes than before, but it didn't.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "piece by piece"? Do `git add -i` or `git add -p` help?

Comment: @Chris: For example, if I see that among a file's changes is a harmless addition of a "print(5);", and I decide I want that change to go into master as well, then I just copy-paste that line into master, and commit.

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand you have a feature branch which has multiple commits pushed to it and you are looking to merge commit by commit from the feature branch into master (possibly to test each commit or something like that)

In that case I would suggest using the git [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) which will get each commit you specify in feature branch and put it on top of the master you want to merge to.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to break `master`, and test what would the merge result of `feature+master` give, you can merge the other way around : `master` into `feature_branch`, and test the resulting `feature_branch`.

If you want to do some "progressive merging", I would suggest looking at the history of `feature_branch`, and merge some intermediate commits.

e.g :

if the history of feature_branch looks like :

```
456eacd  feature completed   <- feature_branch
...
345eacc  first frontend
...
234eacb  config parameters for feature
...
123aeca  completed backend module Module1
...
```

Then run :

```
# from master :
git merge 123aeca
#   test
git merge 234eacb
#   test
git merge 345eacc
#   test
git merge feature_branch
#   test
```